# How to display reactive number of tables at once (with different results)? Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem with displaying reactive number of tables depending on my selection. What I'd like to do is to render as many tables as it's unique records in one column and display them one by one with results for each subgroup.

It'll be easier if I share this example:

```
  dashboardHeader(title = "My App"),

  dashboardSidebar(id="", sidebarMenu(

    menuItem(strong("Tab1"), tabName = "T1", icon = icon("table")))),

  dashboardBody(

    tabItems(

      tabItem(
        tabName="T1",
              fluidRow(tableOutput('tables'))
        )
      )
    )
  )



server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(length(unique(mtcars$gear)), {
    lapply(1:length(unique(mtcars$gear)), 
           function(i){
             output[[paste0('table', i)]]<-renderTable({

               filtered<-mtcars

               a<-list()

               for (j in unique(filtered$gear)){

                 subd <- filtered[filtered$gear == j,] 

                 a[[j]]<-subd

                 }

               for(i in 1:length(a)){
                 a[[i]]
               }

              a[[3]]

             })
           })
  })

  output$tables <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:length(unique(mtcars$gear)), 
           function(i) {
             uiOutput(paste0('table', i))
           })
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I'd like to get out of this code is to have 3 tables (one with summary table for gear=3, one for gear=4 and one for gear=5). What I'm getting right now is 3 tables with results for gear=3.

I've tried to write a for loop which goes through the list but I don't know where I supposed to add this for loop to make it work correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to make a list of tables based on the levels of a factor within the data frame. From there, slight modifications of your `renderUI` should get you the desired results. Note also that I changed the `tables` output to `uiOutput` instead of `tableOutput` because you populate that with `renderUI`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My App"),

  dashboardSidebar(id = "", sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(strong("Tab1"), tabName = "T1", icon = icon("table"))
  )),

  dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(
    tabName = "T1",
    fluidRow(uiOutput('tables'))
  )))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  tables_in_list <- split(x = mtcars, f = mtcars$gear)

  output$tables <- renderUI({
    lapply(seq_along(tables_in_list), function(i)
      renderTable(tables_in_list[[i]]))
  })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```